# Baby version of ''contraction theorem'' to solve IVP

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In my current class I have to deal a lot with differential equations (ODEs). As an optional exercise my Professor suggested to think about the following simplified version of the contraction theorem (for IVP)

> **Problem**: Show that for $0 <t_0 <1$ the mapping $$ f: C([-t_0,t_0]) \to C([-t_0,t_0]), \ f(y)(x):=1 + \int_0^x (t-y(t))dt $$ is a contraction.

---

**My approach**: It is obvious to me what I need to show and thanks to Banach's Fixpoint Theorem what would follow. But I am stuck at $$|f(y(x))-f(g(x))| = \left| \int_0^x (g(t)-y(t))dt \right| \leq \int_0^x|g(t)-y(t)|dt =:I$$
And so I only have to worry about $|g(t)-y(t)|$ but since both functions are continuous and live in the compact space $[-t_0,t_0]$ I get $|g(x)|,|y(x)| \leq t_0 \ \forall t \in [0,x]$

But then I should have that $|g(t)-y(t)| \leq 2t_0$ and from there on I cannot satisfy the contraction requirement anymore $$I \leq 2t_0 |x| \leq 2t_0^2 $$
and what I would really like to have is that $$ I \leq t_0|y(x)-g(x)|, \ \forall x \in [-t_0,t_0]$$
I cannot see a way to obtain that statement though without further constraining the functions $g,y$ and even the variable $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$
\|f(x) - f(y)\|_\infty = \max_{z \in [-t_0, t_0]} \left|1 + \int_0^z (t - x(t)) dt - 1 - \int_0^z (t - y(t)) dt \right| \\
\le \max_{z \in [-t_0, t_0]} \int_0^z |t - x(t) - t + y(t)| dt \\
\le \int_0^{t_0} |x(t) - y(t)| dt \le \int_0^{t_0} \|x - y\|_\infty dt \\
\le t_0 \|x - y\|_\infty.
$$

Since $ 0 <t_0 < 1$, we have a contraction.